# Refer to a file within python package

Tags: python, path, subprocess

I would like to publish on PyPI a python package which has a method of a class that invokes an executable file.

The package is structured as follows:

```
/project
    LICENSE
    MANIFEST.in
    README.md
    setup.py
    /package_name
        classA.py
        classB.py
        executableFile
        classC.py
```

Inside a method of classA.py I call the executable file with the `subprocess` module as follows:

```
subprocess.call('./executableFile', shell=True)
```

If I install the package via `pip` in a virtualenv and I have a main.py script using the installed package as follows:

```
from package.classA import classA

obj_instance = classA()
obj_instance.method() #inside this method there is the subprocess.call(...)
```

The program crashes and tells me that executableFile is not found. I think this happens because the `subprocess.call(...)` searches the executableFile in the folder where there is the main.py instead of the package folder.

How can I specify the exact path of the executable file?

I've tried to use

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('executableFile'))
```

to get the package folder's name, but it returns me the folder path where there is the main.py

How can I solve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your problem as you say _executableFile_ is not found within the _main.py_ **folder**, but _.py_ files are not folders. There is also no _main.py_ file included in your folder structure. You can always use `path.dirname(__file__)`  to get the parent folder of the file, and `path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "executableFile")` to create path to the correct file.

Comment: I've edited the question, I mean the folder where there is the main.py script. Secondly, when installing via pip a python package in a virtualenv, then you need a file (main.py) which uses the API offered by the package. In this case, if you use `path.dirname(__file__)` you get the parent folder of the main.py instead of the parent folder of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setuptools` comes with a [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) framework for handling cases like this.

There's a lot to read there, and I don't know of any good tutorials, but the basic idea is this:

You specify `executableFile` as a file resource. `setuptools` figures out where to stick that at install (or wheel-building) time.

At runtime, you call `resource_filename` to get the path to `executableFile`, and you `subprocess.call` that path.

You probably also want to `atexit` the `cleanup_resources` function.

Under the covers, `pkg_resources` will figure out all the details. With `--inplace` it will be a file in your source tree; with an exploded install, it will be a file somewhere in your `site-packages`; with an egg install, or even as part of a site-packages zipped up by `py2exe` or the like, it will be a file extracted on demand to a cache directory. But you don't have to worry about that; you just get a path and it works.

---

Meanwhile:

> I think this happens because the `subprocess.call(...)` searches the executableFile in the main.py folder instead of the package folder.

It searches the current working directory. That *may* be the same as the directory `main.py` is in, but only if your user ran your program by changing to that directory and running `./main.py` or `python main.py` or similar.

> I've tried to use

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('executableFile'))
```

That isn't going to work, because `abspath` is searching the current working directory too, so it's just a more complicated way of getting the same incorrect path. And then you `dirname` that, and get back the working directory, which is useless.

If you knew the relative path from `package.classA.py` to `executableFile`, you could find it this way:

```
packagedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
execdir = os.path.join(packagedir, '<that relative path>')
execpath = os.path.join(execdir, 'executableFile')
```

Or, if you knew the relative path from `main.py`, you could do the same thing inside `main.py` and store the path somewhere to be used later (e.g., pass it into the `classA` constructor).

But this isn't an ideal solution. The relative path within your source tree may not be the same as the relative path after installation. If your user installs your package as an egg, or bundles your package up in a zipfile with the rest of some application's library, you're just getting the path to the egg or zip, and there is no `executableFile` to be found anywhere relative to that, because it only exists inside the archive. And so on.

The point of `pkg_resources` is to solve all of those issues, and maybe others I didn't think of, and maybe others that don't exist in Python 3.7/pip 10/setuptools 40 but will exist in the Python 3.8/pip 12/setuptools 45 that one of your users is dealing with 18 months from now after you've long forgotten how you got it all working…

Comment: I think I don't get your answer. Do you mean to use `setuptools` with `pkg_resources` while uploading the package on PyPI? And then in the code use `resource_filename`?

Comment: @Frank You do the `pkg_resources` setup in your `setup.py`. It's not run as part of uploading to PyPI, it's run as part of installing your package or building a wheel. In the code, you use `resource_filename` to access the resource you specified in your setup. And you really do need to read the docs (at least the intro and the ResourceManager API parts); there's too many fiddly bits, and no good tutorial that I know of, to just get it by guesswork.

Comment: Ok @abarnert, since I know the relative path I manage to solve with your hint.